# Compare Tables in BigQuery

Tags: compare, google-bigquery

How would I compare two tables (`Table1` and `Table2`) and find all the new entries or changes in `Table2`.

Using SQL Server I can use

```
Select * from Table1
Except
Select * from Table2
```

Here a sample of what I want

**Table1**

```
 A   |  1
 B   |  2
 C   |  3
```

**Table2**

```
 A   |  1
 B   |  2
 C   |  2
 D   |  4
```

So, if I comparing the two tables I want my results to show me the following

```
C   |   2
D   |   4
```

I tried a few statements with no luck.

Comment: I may have figured it out.  I used SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2 WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM Table1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that I have your actual sample dataset, I can write a query that finds every domain in one table that is not on the other table:

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/inbound-acolyte-377:demo.1024 has 24,729,816 rows. https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/inbound-acolyte-377:demo.1025 has 24,732,640 rows.

Let's look at everything in 1025 that is not in 1024:

```
SELECT a.domain
FROM [inbound-acolyte-377:demo.1025] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH [inbound-acolyte-377:demo.1024] b
ON a.domain = b.domain
WHERE b.domain IS NULL
```

Result: 39,629 rows.
(8.1s elapsed, 2.04 GB processed)

Answer (score 2):

To get the differences (given that tkey is your unique row identifier):

```
SELECT a.tkey, a.name, b.name
FROM [your.tableold] a
JOIN EACH [your.tablenew] b
ON a.tkey = b.tkey
WHERE a.name != b.name
LIMIT 100
```

For the new rows, one way is the one you proposed:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table2
WHERE col1 NOT IN
  (SELECT col1 FROM Table1)
```

(you'll have to switch to a JOIN EACH when Table1 gets too large)

Comment: You're correct about JOIN EACH.  The SQL statement runs but I am not getting the appropriate results.  The query is not returning any results.

Comment: Can you create a sample public dataset I can try queries out? Then I could test my answers on your data :).

Comment: I created a demo dataset within my project and provided rights to all authenticated users.  Do you need my project id?

Comment: There are two tables of about 5000 domain names and nameservers.  The tables are named for the date.  I want to know every record in 10252013 that is not in 10242013 (comparing row 1 in one table to all rows in the other table).  This is my query statement that I tried based on the suggestion.  SELECT oct24.domain FROM [demo.10242013] AS oct24
JOIN EACH [demo.10252013] AS oct25
ON oct24.domain = oct25.domain
WHERE oct24.domain != oct25.domain
LIMIT 100;

Comment: project id: yes, please! Then I'll be able to SELECT FROM [your_project:demo.10242013]

Comment: cool, I have a link to your table now https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/inbound-acolyte-377:demo.10242013

Comment: ok, there are absolutely no duplicates between both tables.. did you want to have duplicates?  SELECT domain, COUNT(*) c
FROM [inbound-acolyte-377:demo.10242013], [inbound-acolyte-377:demo.10252013]
GROUP BY 1 HAVING c > 1

Comment: I am surprised to hear that.  I tried to get enough records to have duplicates.  I am uploading the full sets.  An individual table should not have duplicates but we should be able to compare two tables and find duplicates. My results should not show a record if it appears in both tables.

Comment: if you already have them in bigquery, you can copy a table instead of re-uploading (or save the result of a query to the new dataset)

Comment: OK, I uploaded two full runs.  I took the year off of the table names so the tables are 1024 and 1025.

Comment: check the new answer (it'd be great if you can leave the 2 tables up for future reference)