# How to do a diff on two large data sources (csv)

Tags: mysql, hadoop, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift

I have a table with a few billion records. I would like to see how this table has changed in the past month. I have a CSV file of the table export on Jan 1 and again on Jan 31. What would be a good methodology to see how the file has changed over that time. For example:

```
pk        old.name       old.age    new.name        new.age          diff (inferred)
1         david          18         david           18               UNCHANGED
2         charles        17         NULL            NULL             REMOVED
3         bob            19         bob             20               CHANGED
4001      NULL           NULL       bracey          14               ADDED
```

Normally I would just use the unix `diff` command but a single computer/server wouldn't be able to handle this. One idea would be to save two tables to BigQuery and do a full outer join, such as something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19594004/651174. to see how the records have changed?

This is more a conceptual question as to how I would do the above with two csv files, each with billions of records.  My goal is to optimize speed, as this will be a common operation. What would you suggest?

Comment: you might want to take a look at amazon redshift spectrum https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/spectrum/ or amazon athena https://aws.amazon.com/athena/

Comment: Those don't sound like good suggestions. Joins over large CSV files in Athena sounds like a recipe for extremely slow queries. David, what have you tried so far? Did you try using an outer join?

Comment: `This is more a conceptual question` - conceptually - just load your csv files into GBQ and do `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @JonScott what would be the difference between using spectrum or athena? This sounds like an easier solution than BQ if the data is already in s3, as data transfer on files of this size would take an hour or so by itself.

Comment: I would prefer just to iterate over StackOverflow since I have a lot of obligations, sorry. It sounds like loading the files into BigQuery and using a full outer join would be sufficient though.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard would this feature accomplish the same as querying the data on S3 in Athena? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources

Comment: Yes, but you're almost always better off loading the data first and then running queries in terms of performance.

Comment: Spectrum or Athena - I would say redshift spectrum will cost a little more as you will have to run that from withing redshift, however the advantage is that you have redshift a s well, e.g. you could store summary/test/add-on tables in redshift and these would run faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools to compare database tables, such as `pt-table-sync`.  See https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html

You can use pt-table-sync with options `--dry-run --print`, to print how much is different instead of making any changes to data.

The advantage of this tool is that it compares data by smaller chunks instead of attempting to read the whole table in one go. For a table with billions of rows, this would be important.